# LDAPS certificate not working with IP address

Tags: windows-server-2008, ldap, certificate-authority

I have a certificate assigned to my Domain Controller/Certificate Authority that has no subject name assigned but has two FQDN's and and IP in the alternative names under DNS and IPv4 respectively. Both of the DNS names work but the IP address does not work.

I'm sure I'm leaving a lot out here but I'm pretty new to certificates.

In Short, any idea's on why I can use LDAP://FQDN:636/DN=test,DN=com but not LDAP://IP:636/DN=test,DN=com?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense.  I don't think you can actually have a certificate that doesn't have a subject at all.  The validation process is predicated partially on subject names.  Also, what are you trying to do exactly, and what is the expected behaviour, and what is not working about it?

Comment: I got it working (without the need of a primary subject line) the fault was with the way my software was handling LDAPS vs LDAP in the URL.

Comment: In Case anyone else comes across this, I really do want to stress that the primary subject name has not been required in any of my testing, and not in my live environment.

Answer (score 0):

1) It is my understanding that the CN should always be populated. Even if you're never going to use a URL to match the CN, it should have a value in it that you can be sure if it's typed in the address bar of a browser that can talk to this server will get the browser to this server.

2) Where is it that you're getting this error? What are you trying to connect with that's failing, and what is the error message you're getting?

3) The URL you're providing is LDAP://:636... this will never work unless you've enabled LDAP without SSL on port 636 for some reason. You should connect to port 636 using LDAPS://:636, or connect to LDAP://:389 and then flip TLS on with a subsequent command once the connection is established.

Comment: 1) I am able to connect with the FQDN without filling in the CN just dine so I don't believe that will be a problem. 
   
2)I've tried using LDP.exe  
  
3)The URL LDAP://:636 does work with the FQDN, I am looking into using the LDAPS now however.

Sorry about the formatting, can't get the line break to work.

Comment: As far as formatting goes, just use shift-enter in the comment editor to get a new line.

1) I wasn't referring to whether it worked or not, the thing is that the certificate is supposed to guarantee that the site you're connecting to is the site that the certificate was issued to. If the CN in the certificate can be conceivably matched with a URL that doesn't point to your server, then it could allow spoofing. Not saying it will, or that it's even a high risk, just saying as a matter of best practice... Now, to address your actual issue:

Comment: 2)LDP.exe is a good tool, it gives us plenty of output. If you hit "Connection">"Connect", enter in just the IP address in the "Server:" box, change the port to "636" and check the "SSL" checkbox, look at the top few lines of the output. That should give us an SSL related error code or message to work with.